# Start with memcached. What should/can I add to cache?

Tags: django, memcached

I want to start use memcached but I don't know how to start. What should/can I add to cache? (for example in simple blog application). What are the best practices?

Comment: Why do you want to use memcached in the first place?  Give us a little bit more to go on.

Comment: @NathanJhaveri I want to create most optimized app as possible. I read that memcached is good but don't know how to go about it.

Comment: That depends entirely on the kind of data you have. If you want a specific answer please give us more information as to what kind of data you have. Also premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @EWit I have blog posts retrieved from the database using ORM and I display it in template. Standard blog app. I need to understand the general idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basics can be found in the django [cache docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/).

If you have a very basic blog with all the pages somewhat the same you can use the cachemiddleware which just caches everything.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

This will cache the entire website. This however is sometimes a bit too much caching if there is a dynamic element somewhere.

If you have a default view which is the same for all users you can just cache the entire view.

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

@cache_page(60 * 15)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

This creates an entry in the cache of that view for 15 minutes, dependent on the user session/language.

Sometimes however this is too broad, for instance because the pages are updated significantly faster or there is a highly dynamic element located on the page.

If that is the case you'll have to go a bit more low level and manualy maintain your cache.

You basically have two options, template fragment caching or object caching using the low-level api.

For instance you can cache a template fragment of the blog entry.

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 1600 blog_entry blog.id %}
    .. blog_entry ..
{% endcache %}
```

But the performance is highly dependent on how much data is linked to the blog entry.

Or you can cache specific entries of your model.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def blog_entry(request, id):
    entry = cache.get('blog_entry'+str(id))
    if not entry:
        blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=id)
        cache.set('blog_entry'+str(id), blog.entry, 15*60)
        entry = blog.entry
    ... Render page with entry ...
```

My django cache knowledge is a bit rusty so there might be some mistakes. Most of this was made with the data from their docs. Hopefully this clarifies it somewhat.